# Intellisense in VS 2013 for javascript AMD modules

Tags: javascript, intellisense, visual-studio-2013, durandal, js-amd

I’m trying to start programming with Durandal and AMD modules in VS 2013. In c# I’m using intellisense heavily and I would like to use it also in AMD modules. Is there any way to enable this in VS 2013? I have already tried this approach http://landofjoe.com/blog/ill-take-my-durandal-with-intellisense-please but it works only in VS 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You would have to modify the `require.intellisense.js` file yourself to get it to work. This fellow that answered the question linked [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/10238344-d17c-47ea-9248-13a43ca10711/amd-pattern-requirejs-and-visual-studio-intellisense?forum=toolsforwinapps) seems to have gotten it to work for himself.

Answer (score 0):

I've just made intellisense work with Durandal and all other stuff in Visual Studio 2013, **Update 5**, after reading [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/04/20/using-requirejs-with-visual-studio.aspx), though it should work with Update 4 too.

Delete that `require.intellisense.js` from your project, add `_references.js` if you don't have one into your Scripts folder put into the first line this:

```
   /// <reference path="require.js" start-page="/index.html" />
```

Of course reference path should be correct for your case.

That's it! Now you should have intellisense working.